# Linq2SQL get child

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Hello,

I take a classic example, I have a `Customer` table and `Purchase` table, a customer can have several order.

I create a `DBML` file and I drop from "Server Explorer Window" both table to DBML editor, two entities are generated : `Customers` and `Purchases`

I have some objects :

```
public interface IMyCustomer
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Firstname { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
    List<IMyPurchase> Purchases { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomer : IMyCustomer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<IMyPurchase> Orders { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyPurchase
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Code { get; set; }
    DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class MyPurchase : IMyPurchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}

var result = 
    from customer in _dataContext.Customers
    join order in _dataContext.Purchases on customer.Id equals order.IdCustomer
    select new MyCustomer
    {
        Code = customer.Code,
        Firstname = customer.Firstname,
        Lastname = customer.Lastname,
        Id = customer.Id,
        Purchases = _dataContext.Purchases
            .Select(x => x.IdCustomer == customer.Id)
            .Cast<IMyPurchase>()
            .ToList<IMyPurchase>()
    };
```

The linq query work. For an entry of result, I have all information about `customer`, I have the right number of row in `Purchases` but the each properties of each entry of `Purchases` is null. I'd like load the `Customer` info and ALL `purchase`

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you have any translation logic between `Purchase` and `MyPurchase`.

Also the the `Cast<>()` method will try to use implicit casting, but unless your Linq-to-SQL entities implement that interface, it cannot be cast in that way.

My suggestion would be to use something like [AutoMapper](http://nuget.org/packages/automapper) or add translation logic in your linq statement (similar to what you're doing with `MyCustomer`). Something like:

```
var result = 
    from customer in _dataContext.Customers
    join order in _dataContext.Purchases on customer.Id equals order.IdCustomer
    select new MyCustomer
    {
        Code = customer.Code,
        Firstname = customer.Firstname,
        Lastname = customer.Lastname,
        Id = customer.Id,
        Purchases = _dataContext.Purchases
            .Where(x => x.IdCustomer == customer.Id)
            .Select(x => new MyPurchase {
                Id = x.Id,
                Code = x.Code,
                CreationDate = x.CreationDate
            }).ToList();
    };
```

Comment: I have a lot of roundtrip to the database, for each purchase I have a roundtrip, not possible to avoid this ?

Comment: The join that @Johnn Blade uses will only query once. Rather than selecting a new anonymous type as in his example, simply use the same select mechanism as in my answer, but instead of referencing `_dataContext.Purchases` use the joined ObjectSet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample, and where is your customer Id in the Purchase

```
    var items = (from p in _dataContext.Purchases
                 join c in _dataContext.Customers
                 on p.CustomerID equals c.ID
                 where (c.ID == customerId)
                 orderby p.CreationDate descending
                 select new { p, c });

foreach (var data in items)
{
    // do stuff
    int customerId = data.c.ID;
    int purchaseId = data.p.ID;
    // you can acces all properties of both objects
}
```